# How to "npm install packageX" while respecting package-lock.json

Tags: npm, package-lock.json

I want to update a dependency (packageX) without changing a locked dependency of that package, (packageY). In my package-lock.json, I have:

"packageX": {
"requires": {
"packageY": "1.0.0",
}
},

Each time I do "npm install packageX," I'd like to update packageX but have packageY stay on the defined version. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this, may be this link can explain better https://dev.to/saurabhdaware/but-what-the-hell-is-package-lock-json-b04

The story about `package.json` vs `package-lock.json` is tricky: `npm install` does not ignore `package.json` versions, nor does it ignore the `package-lock.json`. What it does is verify that the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` correspond to each other. That is, if the semver versions described in `package.json` fit with the locked versions in `package-lock.json`, npm install will use the latter completely, just like npm ci would.

Now, if you change `package.json` such that the versions in package-lock.json are no longer valid, your npm install will be treated as if you'd done `npm install some-pkg@x.y.z`, where `x.y.z` is the new version in the `package.json` for some-package.